# Docker Alpine image non finding php7.1-xsl

Tags: php, docker, alpine-linux

I am trying to create a container with Alpine Linux that contains [php7-xsl](http://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/armhf/php7-xsl).

My `Dockerfile` is as follows:

```
FROM composer

RUN echo "@edge http://liskamm.alpinelinux.uk/edge/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories; \
    echo "@testing http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories

# Install xls extension
RUN apk --no-cache --update add libxslt-dev php7.1-xsl
```

When I try to build the container, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  php7.1-xsl (virtual):
    provided by: php7-xsl
    required by: world[php7.1-xsl]
The command '/bin/sh -c apk --no-cache --update add libxslt-dev php7.1-xsl@testing' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try `php7-xsl` from Alpine **community** repository

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=*php7-xsl*&branch=edge